# Give accumulo user permissions for all tables

Tags: accumulo

I am trying to grant read/write/bulkimport table permissions to a newly created user account. I have not had any success using wild cards in accumulo shell to grant permissions to all tables at once.

**I have tried the following grant command variants:**

```
grant Table.READ -t * ...
grant Table.READ -t '*' ...
grant Table.READ -t \\* ...
grant Table.READ -p * ...
grant Table.READ -p so_* ...
grant Table.* ...
```

**For -t/-p wildcards, I get either one of the following errors:**
*WARN : No tables found that match your criteria*
*ERROR: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0*
*ERROR: org.apache.accumulo.core.client.TableNotFoundException: Table * does not exist*

**For Table.*, I get:**
*ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such table permission*

I have a lot of tables to grant permissions for, so I am really hoping wildcards are an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards are not currently an option. Granting a user permission for a table should be an action done with care. If you must grant a user permission for a lot of tables, you can create a small Java program to [list the tables](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-core/2.0.0/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/admin/TableOperations.html#list()) and [grant permission](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-core/2.0.0/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/admin/SecurityOperations.html#grantTablePermission(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.apache.accumulo.core.security.TablePermission)).

If you know in advance that a lot of tables are in the same "security domain", you can create a table "namespace", and [grant permission to all tables in the namespace](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-core/2.0.0/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/admin/SecurityOperations.html#grantNamespacePermission(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.apache.accumulo.core.security.NamespacePermission)).

If you must use the shell (which is not the primary API, and provided merely for triage and small trivial actions), you may be able to do it by creating a small script, and executing it as a batch. Run the shell with the `-?` or `--help` option to see the available ways you can execute commands from a file or from STDIN.

If you wish to submit a request to add a wildcard feature, you should [contact the developers](https://accumulo.apache.org/contact-us/) or [open an issue or create a new pull request to propose the change](https://github.com/apache/accumulo/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did exactly what you suggested. I wrote a small script to update the permissions.